# Drupal address showing subfolder aswell

Tags: uri, multi-sites

I am having my site on www.abc.com which is hosted with hostgator. It is installed in public_html, and I installed Drupal in a sub-folder.

Whenever I go to my site, the address bar of the browser shows www.abc.com/techspot, when I would like it to show just www.abc.com.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Comment instead of answer as I'm not sure, but if you dig around in the .htaccess file, I think you'll find a "baseurl" setting. Uncomment and add the directory "/techspot" to it. That could help.

Answer (score 0):

In your htaccess file you can set the rewrite rule:

```
# Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
# VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
# For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
# modify the following line:
# RewriteBase /site
```

Comment: hi did that but still not working.. this is my website, techiequickie.com, so a bit of improvement is that whe I type my site name it is not loading with techiequickie.com/techiequickie anymore it is simply loading techiequickie.com but after the main page the rest of the pages are back to normal showing like this http://techiequickie.com/Techiequickie/user but i want to show only like this  http://techiequickie.com/user

Comment: sure? as far as i can see, it's working... do you have another page, say node/1 etc. to confirm?

Comment: funny enough i cannot get the new password link, it is not showing me anywarning message or if correct username is given not showing any message, if it is sucessful or not..